# using convolution function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a grayscale image. I want to calculate Del for every pixel of image, where

```
del =  sum(absoluteValue(anypixelInensity - it's 8 neighbors Pixel Intensity) 

I = imread('crop.bmp');


%KERNEL
windowSize = 3;
kernel = -1 * ones(3,3);
del = abs(conv2(double(I), double(kernel), 'same'));
disp(I)
disp(del)
```

I want to implement it with matlab `conv2` function.  Which would subtract current pixel intensity from its neighbors and give the absolute sum.

for example:

```
10 2 3
12 15 7
4 5 6

del(1,1) = abs(10-2)+abs(10-12)+abs(10-15)
or del(2,2) = abs(15-10)+abs(15-2)+abs(15-3)+abs(15-12)+abs(15-7)+abs(15-4)+abs(15-5)+abs(15-6)
```

Comment: I don't think you can incorporate the `abs` into a filter in `conv2`. I'll do some checking around and see if there are some special filters that implement this.

Comment: I think this is going to require [nlfilter](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/performing-sliding-neighborhood-operations.html) and a custom function. Let me try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is a bit tricky because, as @AnderBiguri says, the `abs` inside the kernel makes it nonlinear, so `conv2` won't work.

You can, however, use [`nlfilter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/performing-sliding-neighborhood-operations.html) with a custom function. (This implementation uses [`nansum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nansum.html), which is in the Statistics Toolbox. If you don't have access to this function, I can give you an alternate function, it's just easier with `nansum`.)

Another difficulty is that we have to handle the image borders in such a way that they don't mess up the sum. This means that we have handle the image padding ourselves. I've chosen to use `nan` values to pad. I've also been lazy and assumed an odd value for `windowSize`. If this is not always the case, we'll have to adjust the padding.

```
% windowSize assumed to be odd; window assumed to be square
windowSize = 3;

% pad the input image
% padsize is how far the window extends beyond anchor
padsize = floor(windowSize/2);
A = padarray(I, [padsize, padsize], nan);

% create an anonymous function for nlfilter to use
% calculate row/column number of anchor within its neighborhood
anchor = ceil(windowSize/2);
% subtract the anchor element from its neighbors
%   then sum the neighbors *not* equal to NaN
%   (value at anchor position will be 0)
f = @(x) sum(nansum(abs(x-x(anchor,anchor))));

% filter padded image, and then crop off the padding
del = nlfilter(A, [windowSize, windowSize], f);
del = del(1+padsize:end-padsize, 1+padsize:end-padsize);
```

Comment: Great! But beaker for a large image it takes a while to process. Is it possible to make it more faster?

Comment: That does seem to take a long time. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: I don't see an obvious way to speed this up. A double for-loop is actually a little bit faster, but no significantly.

Comment: I see. I used an image for which it took 21 seconds and more!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `conv2` function does the convolution itself.

Given an image, `A` and a kernel `k`

```
imout=conv2(A,k);
```

Will give you the convolution of the kernel over the image.

[Read the documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html)

However, you may want to use [`imfilter`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html), as it s upports better different types of images.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please give your opinion.

Comment: @Nektar if you use `conv2` then you do not need for loops, `conv2` does the job. If instead you want to do it with loops, then you need to write it yourself. Of course, we won't do it for you, because if you need to write it yourself it means that this is homework.

Comment: I have already done it with loop(see the edited question). But I want to implement with conv2  for faster execution. What I am stucked with is defining the kernel. I tried with a small 4*4 matrix but I do not understand how should i define the kernel if I use conv2.

Comment: if you are doing an average kernel, then the kernel would be something that if you multiply by an image in a specific pixel, it would give you the average of the values around it. E.g. a 3x3 average kernel looks like this: `kernel=[1 1 1; 1 1 1; 1 1 1]*1/9`

Comment: I want to subtract any pixel intensity from it's 8 neighbors and then want to take the absolute sum of subtraction result. so how should i define 3*3 kernel for may program. I am experimenting like:
kernel = -1 * ones(3,3);
midPoint = ceil(windowSize / 2); % 41.
kernel(midPoint, midPoint) = windowSize^2 -1;

But no result.

Comment: `kenrnel=[-1 -1 -1; -1 1 -1; -1 -1 -1]` will take a pixel and then substract all the neighbors. just `abs` the result of the convolution for just positive values.

Comment: I tried with the kernel you mentioned but does not give the correct sum!

Comment: @Nektar the fact that the abs is inside the kernel, I think, makes it imposible to do it with standard convolution. Its a non-linear operation, thus unsolvable with linear maths!